# Is it possible to stop my app from showing battery draining notification?

Tags: android

My Android app is using Locationmanger service and when it is in background for a longtime, Android OS(7+ version) showing battery draining notification. I'm afraid will it provoke my customer to uninstall the application. So I just want to know is there anyway to prevent my app from showing this notification.

Comment: Use less battery. Please note that your app may not work as expected on Android 8.0+ anyway, given the changes in background location access.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Those notifications are managed and sent out by the OS. If apps could disable those, everybody would do that and it would defeat the purpose.

The appearance of these notifications is a sign that you should try to decrease your app's battery usage. Perhaps you are holding a wake lock for a long time, or doing other battery inefficient things.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(getPackageName())) {
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

And use in the manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

Then you have to do a lock `PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`

Before submitting this code live on the Play Store please read the conditions where you can use this code, because you can get your update rejected.